# error: unable to recognize "k8s\\service.yaml": no matches for serving.knative.dev/, Kind=Service

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, knative

While trying to deploy my service.yaml file on GKE as a knative service it throws error:

```
kubectl create -f k8s\service.yaml

error: unable to recognize "k8s\\service.yaml": no matches for serving.knative.dev/, Kind=Service
```

[image: knative error]

Am I missing something?

my service.yaml:

```
   apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: revenue-serv
     namespace: default
   spec:
     runLatest:
       configuration:
         revisionTemplate:
           spec:
             container:
               image: "eu.gcr.io/rcup-mza-dev/knative-spring:latest"
```

Comment: do you have the serving components running?

Comment: ideally this should work right? this is as per requirement document. it seems in gke it is no longer valid and cloud run replaced the same. Am I correct?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: yes it is resolved, horizontal autoscaling was not turned on.